# Android App Crashes on Some Devices showing out of memory Error despite of small size images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My app crashes on some devices giving `JAVA.lang.outofmemory` Error while all the data is parsed from a database on an online server. Despite of having small reduced Images (MAX. SIZE 20 Kb) it gives a BITMAP Out of Memory Error. I have attached the crash log and xml for the activity.
Few devices it crashes on include Samsung Note 3, Xiaomi, Mi4

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.humanfox.klisfer.humanfox/com.humanfox.klisfer.humanfox.caps1}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    at com.humanfox.klisfer.humanfox.caps1.onCreate(caps1.java:75)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5246)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2165)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:601)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:434)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
    at 

    android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2513)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2165)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:387)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2072)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.<init>(NetworkImageView.java:61)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.<init>(NetworkImageView.java:57)
        ... 28 more
```

Activity.java

```
public class caps1 extends ActionBarActivity {
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    ImageView collapse;
    public RequestQueue requestQueue,requestQueue1,requestQueue2;
    Long pos;
    private static String url;
    String url2= "http://www.humanfox.com/capsule/recommend.php";
    Context context;
    Capsule caps;
    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    ImageView headshot;
    NetworkImageView recom3,recom2,recom1,headerimage;
    TextView pill1,pill2,pill3,pill4,pill5,pill6;
    Snackbar snackbar;
    ImageLoader imageloader,imageloader2;
    NetworkImageView img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6;
    TextView icon1,icon2,icon3,icon4,text44,text55;
    TextView text444, text555, text666,text6666,text66666,text666666, editorname,editorprof,headernam,headerprof;
    TextView future,quest,beauty, game,que1,ans1,que2,ans2,que3,ans3,que4,ans4,que5,ans5,que6,ans6,que7,ans7,que8,ans8,que9,ans9,que10,ans10,que11,ans11,que12,ans12,quotes,write,reader,recommend,quotebys;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_caps1);

        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1));
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pdialog.setMessage("Loading");
        pdialog.setCancelable(false);
        pos= getIntent().getLongExtra("posi",0);
        Log.d("Opened item id", " "+pos);
        url ="http://www.humanfox.com/capsule/feed.php?id=";
        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar1);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Capsule");
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        //setPalette();
        snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(collapsingToolbarLayout, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    }
                });
        img1= (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        img2= (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
        img3= (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.image3);
        img4= (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.image4);
        img5= (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.image5);
        img6= (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.image6);
        headerimage= (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.collapse);
        text44=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text44);
        text55=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text55);
        icon1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.icon1);
        icon2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.icon2);
        icon3= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.icon3);
        icon4= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.icon4);

        quotebys = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quoteby);
        recommend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recommend);
        headshot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.headsh1);

        pill1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pill1);
        pill2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pill2);
        pill3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pill3);
        pill4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pill4);
        pill5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pill5);
        pill6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pill6);

        recom1 =(NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.recom1);
        recom2 =(NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.recom2);
        recom3 =(NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.recom3);
        editorname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.writtenby);
        editorprof=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.reader);

        headernam=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.headername);
        headerprof=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.headerprofession);
        text444= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text444);
        text555= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text555);
        text666= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text666);
        text6666= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text6666);
        text66666= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text66666);
        text666666= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text666666);



        quotes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
        que1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que1);
        ans1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans1);
        que2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que2);
        ans2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans2);
        que3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que3);
        ans3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans3);
        que4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que4);
        ans4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans4);
        que5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que5);
        ans5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans5);
        que6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que6);
        ans6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans6);
        que7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que7);
        ans7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans7);
        que8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que8);
        ans8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans8);
        que9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que9);
        ans9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans9);
        que10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que10);
        ans10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans10);

        Typeface icons = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
        Typeface face3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf");
        Typeface face2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        Typeface face4 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");

        icon1.setTypeface(icons);
        icon2.setTypeface(icons);
        icon3.setTypeface(icons);
        icon4.setTypeface(icons);

        quotebys.setTypeface(face);
        editorprof.setTypeface(face);
        recommend.setTypeface(face3);
        editorname.setTypeface(face);
        quotes.setTypeface(face);

        text444.setTypeface(face3);
        text555.setTypeface(face3);
        text666.setTypeface(face3);
        text6666.setTypeface(face);
        text66666.setTypeface(face);
        text666666.setTypeface(face);


        que1.setTypeface(face2);
        ans1.setTypeface(face);
        que2.setTypeface(face2);
        ans2.setTypeface(face);
        que3.setTypeface(face2);
        ans3.setTypeface(face);
        que4.setTypeface(face2);
        ans4.setTypeface(face);
        que5.setTypeface(face2);
        ans5.setTypeface(face);
        que6.setTypeface(face2);
        ans6.setTypeface(face);
        que7.setTypeface(face2);
        ans7.setTypeface(face);
        que8.setTypeface(face2);
        ans8.setTypeface(face);
        que9.setTypeface(face2);
        ans9.setTypeface(face);
        que10.setTypeface(face2);
        ans10.setTypeface(face);


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        fetchthedata(pos);
        requestQueue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest or = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url2, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject recom = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                        String pil1 = recom.getString("name1");
                        String pil2 = recom.getString("profession1");
                        String re1 = recom.getString("image1");
                        final long id1 =recom.getLong("id1");
                        Log.d("1st id is:",""+id1);
                        imageloader = MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
                        re1.replace("\\"," ");
                        re1.trim();

                        String pil3 = recom.getString("name2");
                        String pil4 = recom.getString("profession2");
                        String re2 = recom.getString("image2");
                        final long id2 =recom.getLong("id2");
                        Log.d("2nd id is:",""+id2);
                        re2.replace("\\"," ");
                        re2.trim();

                        String pil5 = recom.getString("name3");
                        String pil6 = recom.getString("profession3");
                        String re3 = recom.getString("image3");
                        final long id3 =recom.getLong("id3");
                        Log.d("3rd id is:",""+id3);
                        re3.replace("\\"," ");
                        re3.trim();

                        pill1.setText(pil1);
                        pill2.setText(pil2);
                        pill3.setText(pil3);
                        pill4.setText(pil4);
                        pill5.setText(pil5);
                        pill6.setText(pil6);
                        //recom1.setImage(ImageSource.uri(re1));
                        //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(re1).into(recom1);

                         recom1.setImageUrl(re1,imageloader);
                        //imageloader.get(re1, ImageLoader.getImageListener(img6,R.drawable.ic_launcher,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
                        recom1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                Intent i = new Intent(caps1.this, caps2.class).putExtra("posi", id1);

                                startActivity(i);
                                Log.d("clicked item: ", "" + id1);

                            }
                        });
                        //recom2.setImage(ImageSource.uri(re2));
                        //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(re2).into(recom2);

                        recom2.setImageUrl(re2,imageloader);
                        //imageloader.get(re2, ImageLoader.getImageListener(img6,R.drawable.ic_launcher,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
                        recom2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                Intent i = new Intent(caps1.this,caps2.class).putExtra("posi",id2);

                                startActivity(i);
                                Log.d("clicked item: " ,""+id2);

                            }
                        });
                        //recom3.setImage(ImageSource.uri(re3));
                        //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(re3).into(recom3);

                        recom3.setImageUrl(re3,imageloader);
                        //imageloader.get(re3, ImageLoader.getImageListener(img6,R.drawable.ic_launcher,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
                        recom3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                Intent i = new Intent(caps1.this,caps2.class).putExtra("posi",id3);

                                startActivity(i);

                                Log.d("clicked item: " ,""+id3);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue1.add(or);


    }

    public void fetchthedata(long id){
        showpDialog();
        JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url+id , null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject capsule = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String m1 = capsule.getString("m1");
                        imageloader = MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
                        m1.replace("\\"," ");
                        m1.trim();
                        String caphead = capsule.getString("person_headshot");
                        caphead.replace("\\"," ");
                        caphead.trim();
                        String writerhead = capsule.getString("editor_headshot");
                        String m2 = capsule.getString("m2");
                        m2.replace("\\"," ");
                        m2.trim();
                        String m3 = capsule.getString("m3");
                        m3.replace("\\"," ");
                        m3.trim();
                        String m4 = capsule.getString("m4");
                        m4.replace("\\"," ");
                        m4.trim();
                        String m5 = capsule.getString("m5");
                        m5.replace("\\"," ");
                        m5.trim();
                        String m6 = capsule.getString("m6");
                        m6.replace("\\"," ");
                        m6.trim();
                        String editorpro = capsule.getString("editor_profession");
                        String editornam = capsule.getString("editor_name");
                        String quote = capsule.getString("quote");
                        String pro = capsule.getString("profession");
                        String headerimag = capsule.getString("mheader");
                        headerimag.replace("\\"," ");
                        headerimag.trim();
                        String quoteby = capsule.getString("name");
                        String bday = capsule.getString("birthday");
                        String plac = capsule.getString("place");
                        String q1 = capsule.getString("q1");
                        String a1 = capsule.getString("a1");
                        String q2 = capsule.getString("q2");
                        String a2 = capsule.getString("a2");
                        String q3 = capsule.getString("q3");
                        String a3 = capsule.getString("a3");
                        String q4 = capsule.getString("q4");
                        String a4 = capsule.getString("a4");
                        String q5 = capsule.getString("q5");
                        String a5 = capsule.getString("a5");
                        String q6 = capsule.getString("q6");
                        String a6 = capsule.getString("a6");
                        String q7 = capsule.getString("q7");
                        String a7 = capsule.getString("a7");
                        String q8 = capsule.getString("q8");
                        String a8 = capsule.getString("a8");
                        String q9 = capsule.getString("q9");
                        String a9 = capsule.getString("a9");
                        String q10 = capsule.getString("q10");
                        String a10 = capsule.getString("a10");
                        String reads= capsule.getString("hits");
                        String share= capsule.getString("shares");
                        text44.setText(reads);
                        text55.setText(share);
                        text666.setText(quoteby);
                        text6666.setText(pro);
                        text66666.setText(bday);
                        text666666.setText(plac);
                        que1.setText(q1);
                        ans1.setText(a1);
                        que2.setText(q2);
                        ans2.setText(a2);
                        que3.setText(q3);
                        ans3.setText(a3);
                        que4.setText(q4);
                        ans4.setText(a4);
                        que5.setText(q5);
                        ans5.setText(a5);
                        que6.setText(q6);
                        ans6.setText(a6);
                        que7.setText(q7);
                        ans7.setText(a7);
                        que8.setText(q8);
                        ans8.setText(a8);
                        que9.setText(q9);
                        ans9.setText(a9);
                        que10.setText(q10);
                        ans10.setText(a10);
                        quotes.setText(quote);
                        quotebys.append(quoteby);
                        editorname.append(editornam);
                        editorprof.setText(editorpro);
                        headernam.setText(quoteby);
                        headerprof.setText(pro);
                        Log.d("TAG",""+m1);
                        //imageloader.get(headerimag, ImageLoader.getImageListener(headerimage, R.drawable.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
                        headerimage.setImageUrl(headerimag,imageloader);
                        //imageloader.get(m1, ImageLoader.getImageListener(img1, R.drawable.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
                        img1.setImageUrl(m1,imageloader);

                        //imageloader.get(m2, ImageLoader.getImageListener(img2,R.drawable.ic_launcher,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
                        img2.setImageUrl(m2,imageloader);
                        //imageloader.get(m3, ImageLoader.getImageListener(img3,R.drawable.ic_launcher,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
                        img3.setImageUrl(m3,imageloader);
                        //imageloader.get(m4, ImageLoader.getImageListener(img4,R.drawable.ic_launcher,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
                        img4.setImageUrl(m4,imageloader);
                        //imageloader.get(m5, ImageLoader.getImageListener(img5,R.drawable.ic_launcher,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
                        img5.setImageUrl(m5,imageloader);
                        //imageloader.get(m5, ImageLoader.getImageListener(img6,R.drawable.ic_launcher,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
                        img6.setImageUrl(m6,imageloader);
                        /*Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(m1).into(img1);
                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(m2).into(img2);
                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(m3).into(img3);
                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(m4).into(img4);
                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(m5).into(img5);
                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(m6).into(img6);
                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(headerimag).into(headerimage);*/
                        /*headerimage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(headerimag));
                        img1.setImage(ImageSource.uri(m1));
                        img2.setImage(ImageSource.uri(m2));
                        img3.setImage(ImageSource.uri(m3));
                        img4.setImage(ImageSource.uri(m4));
                        img5.setImage(ImageSource.uri(m5));
                        img6.setImage(ImageSource.uri(m6));*/



                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }hidepDialog();

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jor);

    }


    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    /*private void setPalette() {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) collapse.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                int primaryDark = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark);
                int primary = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary);
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(primary));
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getDarkVibrantColor(primaryDark));
            }
        });

    }*/


    public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
        int targetWidth = 50;
        int targetHeight = 50;
        Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
                targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
                ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
                (Math.min(((float) targetWidth),
                        ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                Path.Direction.CCW);

        canvas.clipPath(path);
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
        canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap,
                new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                        sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
                new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
        return targetBitmap;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pdialog.isShowing())
            pdialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pdialog.isShowing())
            pdialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: 20 KiB is for uncompressed bitmaps or PNGs/JPEGs? 20 KiB PNG can eat quite a lot of memory because it is stored uncompressed in the memory. Also that five fonts will probably eat a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of work on main Activity thread that's why Out of memory Exception occurs.

Do in Background Thread.

For Images from URL you should use Caching Library Like [GLIDE](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [PICASSO](https://github.com/square/picasso) These will Do image caching in background and out of memory exception will never occur

Comment: oom is not actually related to doing too long operations in the main thread.

xiaomi redmiis do something differently and thus end up using more memory during decode, it would be nice to know what or why.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a lot of work on the Main Thread (or UIThread) does not lead to OOM.

I dealth with my share of OOM, still have a headache now and then.

I, too, advice using a library like Picasso like Muhammad. I use Nostra13 UniversalImageLoader. Nostra13 has an LRUCache mechanism to handle memory consumption. Haven't checked how Picasso does it though, I like it.

If you have to decode some high quality images from your resources, here's a good starter point which helped me a lot. Good luck.

[Displaying Bitmaps Efficently Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check what folder contains your images. When I was learning Android I saw similar errors.  Moving the images to drawable-nodpi fixed the issue for me.